# How to avoid negative margins and fit width of element?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm creating pager (maybe I'm wrong with the name) widget on my page and I am stuck with problem.
[image]
I'm using bootstrap-style pre-calculated width for each pager's step to provide uniform width. But the problem is each dot is aligned at center of each step `div` including first and last element. But this results in an empty space that appears at the first and last elements.
[image]

The only solution that I could find is set negative margin to pager container and fit left and right dot to page borders, but that method has a problems:

- I need to set margin value individually for each number of steps manually
- Extra margin cause undesirable horizontal scroll

How can i fix this problems?

Here is pager structure:

```
<div class="pager-bar row pb-6">
   <div class="pb-step pb-complete">
       <div class="pb-step-label">1</div>
       <div class="pb-progress">
           <div class="pb-progress-bar"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="pb-dot"></span></div>
   <div class="pb-step pb-complete pb-active">
       <div class="pb-step-label">2</div>
       <div class="pb-progress">
           <div class="pb-progress-bar"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="pb-dot"></span></div>
   <div class="pb-step pb-disabled">
       <div class="pb-step-label">3</div>
       <div class="pb-progress">
           <div class="pb-progress-bar"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="pb-dot"></span></div>
   <div class="pb-step pb-disabled">
       <div class="pb-step-label">4</div>
       <div class="pb-progress">
           <div class="pb-progress-bar"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="pb-dot"></span></div>
   <div class="pb-step pb-disabled">
       <div class="pb-step-label">5</div>
       <div class="pb-progress">
           <div class="pb-progress-bar"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="pb-dot"></span></div>
   <div class="pb-step pb-disabled">
       <div class="pb-step-label">6</div>
       <div class="pb-progress">
           <div class="pb-progress-bar"></div>
       </div>
       <span class="pb-dot"></span></div>
</div>
```

Styles (SCSS):

```
@import "../colors";

$pb-margin-6: -130px;
$pb-margin-3: -302px;

.pager-bar {
 height: 100px;
 padding-top: 45px;

 &.row {
   > .pb-step {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     min-height: 1px;
   }

   &.pb-6 {
     margin-left: $pb-margin-6;
     margin-right: $pb-margin-6;

     > .pb-step {
       width: (100% / 6);
     }
   }

   &.pb-3 {
     margin-left: $pb-margin-3;
     margin-right: $pb-margin-3;

     > .pb-step {
       width: (100% / 3);
     }
   }
 }

 > .pb-step {
   padding: 0;

   .pb-step-label {
     color: $coral;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: 600;
     font-size: 24px;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
   }

   > .pb-dot {
     position: absolute;
     width: 10px;
     height: 10px;
     display: block;
     background: $coral;
     top: 55px;
     left: 50%;
     margin-top: -15px;
     margin-left: -5px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     cursor: pointer;
   }

   > .pb-progress {
     position: relative;
     height: 2px;
     margin: 10px 0;

     > .pb-progress-bar {
       width: 0;
       height: 100%;
       background: $coral;
     }
   }

   &.pb-complete {
     > .pb-progress > .pb-progress-bar {
       width: 100%;
     }
   }

   &.pb-active {
     > .pb-progress > .pb-progress-bar {
       width: 50%;
     }

     &:first-of-type {
       > .pb-progress > .pb-progress-bar {
         width: 0;
       }
     }

     > .pb-step-label {
       color: $coral;
       font-weight: 600;
     }
   }

   &:first-child.pb-current > .pb-progress > .pb-progress-bar {
     width: 0;
   }

   &:last-child.pb-current > .pb-progress > .pb-progress-bar {
     width: 100%;
   }

   &.pb-disabled {
     .pb-dot {
       background-color: #ddd;
       cursor: default;
       &:after {
         opacity: 0;
       }
     }

     .pb-step-label {
       color: $warm-grey;
       font-weight: 300;
     }
   }

   &:first-child > .pb-progress {
     left: 50%;
     width: 50%;
   }

   &:last-child > .pb-progress {
     width: 50%;
   }

   .pb-progress {
     background-color: #ddd;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout and move `pb-progress` out of `pb-step`, you can simplify a lot of the HTML and CSS:

http://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/RoMYBQ?editors=1100

HTML

```
<div class="pager-bar">

    <div class="pb-step">
        <div class="pb-step-label">1</div>
        <span class="pb-dot"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-progress"></div>

    <div class="pb-step pb-active">
        <div class="pb-step-label">2</div>
        <span class="pb-dot"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-progress"></div>

    <div class="pb-step">
        <div class="pb-step-label">3</div>
        <span class="pb-dot"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="pb-progress"></div>

    ...

</div>
```

SCSS

```
$bullet-size: 10px;
$color-active: coral;
$color-disabled: gainsboro;

.pager-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;

    .pb-step {
        flex: 0 0 $bullet-size;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: $bullet-size;

        color: $color-active;
        &.pb-active ~ .pb-step {
            color: $color-disabled;
        }

        .pb-dot {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 50%;
            width: $bullet-size;
            height: $bullet-size;
            margin-left: -$bullet-size/2;
            border-radius: 100%;
            background: currentColor;
        }
    }

    .pb-progress {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        height: 2px;
        margin: 0 -$bullet-size;
        margin-bottom: calc( #{$bullet-size/2} - 1px );

        background: $color-active;
        @at-root .pb-step.pb-active ~ .pb-progress {
            background: $color-disabled;
        }

        &:last-child {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```